# Is this a ColdFusion Bug in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

This is a valid query to return emails surrounded by single quotes from the users table.

```
SELECT  '''' +email + '''' as email
FROM    users
where fname = @fname
```

Yet when I try to do this in a cfscript (cf9) query like this :

```
var q = new Query(datasource="warewithal");
q.setSQL("SELECT  '''' +email + '''' as email
                FROM users where firstName= :firstName ");
q.addParam(name="firstName", value=trim(firstName), cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
```

what I end up with is

```
Email
+email+
```

when I expected (and get by running the query in an analyzer)

```
Email
'bozo@clowns.com'
```

the cfscript is doing a perserveSingleQuote and not letting me add the single quote to the output.

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try it with just two single quotes instead of 4? how about 3, 5 or 6?

Comment: What database type are you using? (Always good to include that in the tags of query related questions).

Comment: (Edit) While it is definitely related to the use of `preserveSingleQuotes` in `Query.cfc`, I got a different result testing your code against SQL Server (database syntax error). So it is not clear whether it is a bug - or if it is - whether it is strictly a CF bug. Not sure why you need to do this, but as a workaround you either add it in the presentation layer with CF code (more typical) or possibly use your database's string functions to generate the single quote. ie In SQL Server: `SELECT char(39) + email + char(39) AS Email ...`

Comment: I am trying to understand why you would need the result to be wrapped in single quotes. It might be easier to just put single quotes around the email address when you need to output, no?

Comment: You could also try using your DBMS built in concatinate functions like concat() in SQL server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question in your headline: no, this is not a bug in CFScript. What you are demonstrating has nothing to do with CFScript at all.

However to answer the question you *mean* to be asking: yes, you have found a bug in Query.cfc.

Here's some code that demonstrates the bug (and demonstrates that it has nothing to do with CFScript, and everything to do with Query.cfc).

This code works fine:

```
<cfset query = new Query(datasource="scratch_mssql")>
<cfset query.setSql("
    SELECT  '''' + email + '''' as email
    FROM    users
    WHERE   firstName = '#firstName#'   
")>
<cfset emailAddresses = query.execute().getResult()> 
<cfdump var="#emailAddresses#">
```

Note that I have hard-coded the filter value into the SQL string. Yuck.

This code errors:

```
<cfset query = new Query(datasource="scratch_mssql")>
<cfset query.setSql("
    SELECT  '''' + email + '''' as email
    FROM    users
    WHERE   firstName = :firstname  
")>
<cfset query.addParam(name="firstname", value=firstName, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR")>
<cfset emailAddresses = query.execute().getResult()> 
<cfdump var="#emailAddresses#">
```

The error for me is:

`[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]An object or column name is missing or empty.` `For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements,`
`look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.`

FYI: The SQL that CF had passed to the DB was:

```
SELECT  '' '' + email + '' '' as email FROM users WHERE firstName = (param 1)
```

To prove that it's caused by ColdFusion mishandling your single quotes, this works:

```
<cfset query = new Query(datasource="scratch_mssql")>
<cfset query.setSql("
    SELECT  email as email
    FROM    users
    WHERE   firstName = :firstname  
")>
<cfset query.addParam(name="firstname", value=firstName, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR")>
<cfset emailAddresses = query.execute().getResult()> 
<cfdump var="#emailAddresses#">
```

So I'd raise a [bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/) for this if I was you. Note: it's the same on CF9.0.2 and CF10.0.7

But, equally... if I was you I'd not be putting those quotes in there anyhow. Unless there's a very good reason, stick 'em in when you're doing the display, not when you're doing the data processing. I presume they're there for display purposes?

Comment: Adam, what was the generated SQL in the example that errored?

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with this post you guys messed with back in 2010 lol. http://forums.adobe.com/message/2986794

Comment: @Travis - Good find. I discovered the same thing debugging it.. only a few hours late ;) CF10's `Query.cfc` seems to include a similar `includeEmptyFields=true` fix. Unfortunately the loop logic also adds an extra space between the doubled single quotes. That is what causes the sql server syntax error I mentioned earlier. Remove the space and it works fine.

Comment: @Travis: I've updated the text to include the SQL. It's the same on both CF9 + 10.

Comment: Just an observation: railo 4.0.2 also has this problem, with this code.

Comment: Oh wow that is bizarre, but it does explain the error you got

Comment: @AdamCameron - Sounds like Railo might be using similar logic. I guess neither engine accounted for this scenario ie surrounding a column/value with single quotes. What does the Railo sql look like (I cannot test it right now)?

Comment: @Leigh. It's the same. Except spread over 40-odd lines (they have some whitespace control issues, it would seem...)

Comment: Thanks for all of the input.  We did end up adding the single quotes in a different way.  As several people suggested there is always a work around.  Unfortunately since the sql syntax was correct we wasted a bit of time trying to figure out what we had done wrong.  That's part of the game though.  @Adam Thanks for registering this bug.

Comment: @Lance - He did not say *he* filed a bug report, he suggested that *you* do that ;) Also, you should post your final query as an "answer", so it it is easier for others to find in the future. Be sure to include your database type since sql syntax varies by database type (and you forgot to include it in the question tags).

Comment: @AdamCameron - Ah, okay thanks. Interesting they ended up with a similar approach and bug. Oh the joys string parsing...

Comment: @Lance: yeah, I suggested YOU raise the bug. I just gave you the URL to do so. If you post the bug ref back here, I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just got bit by this issue was well.  What seems to work is a simple fix to your Query.cfc object (/[YOUR-CF-INSTALL]/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/Query.cfc).  In the replaceDelimsWithMarkers() function, update this line (LN 341 for me)

```
newSql = newSql & SINGLEQUOTE & sqlArray[i] & SINGLEQUOTE & " ";
```

by removing the quoted space at the end, so it is:

```
newSql = newSql & SINGLEQUOTE & sqlArray[i] & SINGLEQUOTE & "";
```

Then it works great. I was looking up users, and needed to find one where last name is "O'Neill".  No matter what I did I was getting "O' 'Neill" which as you state fails.

Can you think of any cases where this change/fix would have a negative impact? I can't off the top of my head, but for now we are going to copy the query.cfc file, rename it and use it as a custom tag ONLY when we need to run queries where we suspect extra apostrophe's might be used.  The only difference will be this one little change.